# Using a NSTimer to switch between two UIImageViews, one after another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nstimer

I've seen similar questions but none of the answers given have worked in my case. I want to give my character the illusion that he is walking, but he will really remain at the same coordinates and the background will be moving instead, the way I want to do this is to use a `IBAction` to start my timer, my code so far looks like this.

```
-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender
{    
    PersonMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(PersonMovement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

now using that timer, every 0.05 seconds I want the `UIImageView` of my person to alternate between (step1.png and step2.png) relaying back and forth.

Comment: Show your implementation of the `PersonMovement` method where you attempt to switch images.

Comment: @rmaddy there is nothing much there i dont know what im doing really so i just have it there ready for code to be put into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use `UIImageView`s `animationImages` and `animationDuration` properties to accomplish this swapping.

Your `animationImages` array would be your two images and your `animationDuration` would be `0.1` to show both over the span of 0.1 seconds. Then call `startAnimating` to start the sequence

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    imageView.animationImages = @[image1, image2];
    imageView.animationDuration = 0.1;
    [imageView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: you think you could give me an example code honestly? this isnt working... here is what i have....     -(void)PersonMovement
{

    UIImageView *step1;
    NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"step1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"step2.png"], nil];
    
    
    step1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"step1.png"]];
    [step1 setAnimationImages:imagesArray];
    
    [step1 setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [step1 setAnimationRepeatCount:100];
    [step1 startAnimating];

}

Comment: I added a sample that I just tested. It looks like your code doesn't create UIImageView and add it to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much, now one last thing, how do i change the size of the image? the images that are animating are a lot bigger then they are supposed to be....

Comment: If your all images are all the same size, then set the size in the frame when creating the `UIImageView`: `CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, width, height)`.

If your images are different size, then set the size to the largest one, then set `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, since you've helped me this much mind helping out a little more? I'm trying to make a touch event move my animated object up 10 pixel here is what I've tried but it didn't work... if (UITouchPhaseBegan){
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10 , 407 + 10, 45, 45)];
        
    }
    if (UITouchPhaseEnded){
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 407 - 10, 45, 45)];
    }
any ideas? I also tried simply musing -(void)touchesBegan....* and tried doing writing code in there to do it, but I had no luck... thanks for the help!